# excel file is geting corrupted when writing large data using jxl

Tags: groovy, soapui, jxl

I am trying to do some automation using groovy. I am taking response data another request and storing both request and both output in excel using jxl jars. but if I do that my excel file is getting corrupted. but when I did single request response it's working fine. so I want to know is there any memory issues with jxl??if yes how to overcome that??

Here's my script:

```
    import jxl.*
    import jxl.write.*
    import groovy.sql.Sql


    //Datasheet read define start
    def projectLocation="E:/"
    def dataFileLocation=projectLocation+"zip.xls"
    def workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(dataFileLocation))
    def readSheet = workbook.getSheet(0)
    def rowCount = readSheet.getRows()
    def colCount = readSheet.getColumns()

    def myTestCase = context.testCase
    //db config
    def url = 'jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/'
    def user = 'sa'
    def password = ''
    def driver = 'org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver'
    def sql = Sql.newInstance(url, user, password, driver)

    propTestStep = myTestCase.getTestStepByName("Properties");
    //Datasheet read end

    //Content Write define start
    WorkbookSettings s = new WorkbookSettings();  
    s.setUseTemporaryFileDuringWrite(true);  
   // s.setInitialFileSize(100000000)

    WritableWorkbook workbook1 = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(projectLocation+"output1.xls"),s)
    WritableSheet writeSheet = workbook1.createSheet("new", 0)
    //
    //WritableWorkbook workbook2 = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(projectLocation+"output2.xls"))
    //WritableSheet writeSheet1 = workbook2.createSheet("newOutput", 0)
    def project = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project
    def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
    //Content Write define end


    for(int i = 1;i < rowCount; i++)
                    {

                                    for(int j = 0;j < colCount; j++)
                                                    {

                                                                    val= readSheet.getCell(j,i).getContents()
                                                                   // log.info "before storing in zip val="+ val
                                                                   // propTestStep.setPropertyValue("zip",val)
                                                                    def req=groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "GetInfoByZIP#Request" )
                                                                    req["//web:USZip"] = val

                                                                    req.updateProperty()
                                                                    testRunner.runTestStep( project.testSuites['USZipSoap12 TestSuite'].testCases['GetInfoByZIP TestCase'].testSteps['GetInfoByZIP'] )

                                                                  //  log.info "before sending to db val="+val
                       sql.eachRow('select state,city from zip where zip=?',[val]){ row ->
                         st= row.state
                         ct= row.city
                        }

                                                                    //log.info st+" "+ct
                                                                    def res=groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "GetInfoByZIP#Response" )
                        def state = res.getNodeValues( "//STATE" )
                        def city=res.getNodeValues("//CITY")

                        def ct1=city[0]
                         log.info ct +" " +  ct1
                        if(ct1.equalsIgnoreCase(ct)){
                                   // log.info  "city equals"
                        }
                        else{
                                   // log.info "not eq"
                        }


                                                                       def req1=groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "GetInfoByState#Request" )
                                                                        req1["//web:USState"]=state[0]
                                                                        req1.updateProperty()

                                                                         testRunner.runTestStep( project.testSuites['USZipSoap12 TestSuite'].testCases['GetInfoByZIP TestCase'].testSteps['GetInfoByState'] )

                                                                        def respo1= testRunner.testCase.testSteps["GetInfoByState"].testRequest.response.contentAsString
                                                                    Label labelReq = new Label(j,i,context.testCase.getTestStepByName("GetInfoByZIP").getProperty("request").value)
                                                                    Label labelReq1 = new Label(j+2,i,context.testCase.getTestStepByName("GetInfoByState").getProperty("request").value)

                                                                    def response = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["GetInfoByZIP"].testRequest.response.contentAsString
                                                                    Label labelResp = new Label(j+1,i,response);
                                                                                                                        Label labelResp1 = new Label(j+3,i,respo1);
                                                                    writeSheet.addCell(labelReq)
                                                                    writeSheet.addCell(labelResp);
                                                         log.info respo1
                                                                      writeSheet.addCell(labelReq1)
                                                                    writeSheet.addCell(labelResp1);

                                                    }

                    }
    workbook1.write()
    workbook1.close()
```

Comment: Edit the question and show the script that you have.

Comment: edited please see once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are response data exceeding the cell limit of excel. You can check that thing with copy paste the response in word check how many characters are there. Excel can contain 32,767 char in one line. if it is more than that it may get corrupt.

Comment: Thanks Ya Its the same problem you mentioned I used different request its working fine..

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you're overriding something unintentionally. I can't tell what it is. But, a good starting point is with much cleaner code. So I recommend using [Frosted Sheets](https://bitbucket.org/erosa/frostedsheets) (backed by Apache POI) instead of JXL. It makes working with workbooks **MUCH** *much* much easier.

I wrote the library because I got tired of seeing some of the nastiest code ever, and I knew it could be done more... Groovy-ly.

```
import com.emmanuelrosa.frostedsheets.*
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook
import groovy.sql.Sql

def projectLocation="E:/"
def dataFileLocation="${projectLocation}zip.xls"
def workbook = new FrostedWorkbook(new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(dataFileLocation)))
def rowCount = readSheet.getRows()
def colCount = readSheet.getColumns()

def myTestCase = context.testCase
def url = 'jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/'
def user = 'sa'
def password = ''
def driver = 'org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver'
def sql = Sql.newInstance(url, user, password, driver)

propTestStep = myTestCase.getTestStepByName("Properties");

def workbook1 = FrostedWorkbook.createXLS()
def writeSheet = workbook1['new']
def project = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)

/*
 * cellIterator() returns a special Iterator which traverses
 * through the cells by row, then column; top-down, left-right.
 * It eliminates the need for nested loops.
 */
workbook[0].cellIterator().each { cell ->
    req["//web:USZip"] = cell.cellValue
    def req=groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "GetInfoByZIP#Request" )

    req.updateProperty()
    testRunner.runTestStep( project.testSuites['USZipSoap12 TestSuite'].testCases['GetInfoByZIP TestCase'].testSteps['GetInfoByZIP'] )

    sql.eachRow('select state,city from zip where zip=?',[val]) { row ->
        st= row.state
        ct= row.city
    }

    def res=groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "GetInfoByZIP#Response" )
    def state = res.getNodeValues( "//STATE" )
    def city=res.getNodeValues("//CITY")

    def ct1=city[0]
    log.info ct +" " +  ct1

    if(ct1.equalsIgnoreCase(ct)) {
           // log.info  "city equals"
    }
    else{
           // log.info "not eq"
    }

    def req1=groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "GetInfoByState#Request" )
    req1["//web:USState"]=state[0]
    req1.updateProperty()

    testRunner.runTestStep( project.testSuites['USZipSoap12 TestSuite'].testCases['GetInfoByZIP TestCase'].testSteps['GetInfoByState'] )

    writeSheet[cell.rowIndex + 1].with {
        def stateInfo = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["GetInfoByState"].testRequest.response.contentAsString
        def zipValue = context.testCase.getTestStepByName("GetInfoByZIP").getProperty("request").value
        def stateValue = context.testCase.getTestStepByName("GetInfoByState").getProperty("request").value
        def zipInfo = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["GetInfoByZIP"].testRequest.response.contentAsString

        // Add the columns to the row
        append [zipValue, zipInfo, stateValue, stateInfo]
    }

}

new FileOutputStream("${projectLocation}output1.xls").withStream { stream ->
    workbook1.write(stream)
}
```

Comment: it's showing me FrostedWorkBook not able to resolve.m using POI 3.14

Comment: First, make sure you have set up the Maven repo (resolver) *and* the dependency as described in the README. The .jar is not in Maven Central. If it grabbed POI 3.14-beta1 then you're set. Next, make sure you spell the class name correctly. It's `FrostedWorkbook` with lowecase *b*.